# Deserialize Json with properties splited in 2 classes

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON from an api request, about solar radiation data.
The json request is made in fragment way. As you can see, the "inputs" class, has a Location property, but the "Meta" class also has a "inputs" class and a "location" property, is like the info is spread into 2 sections. This happens also with other 3 classes.

I´ve made some test with automatic class creation like Json2csharp or //app.quicktype.io. The first one create only 1 class that merge properties called Input, but the other page create 2 different classes, like Json does (input and input1).

The first aproach doesnt work, and the second one I didn´t try it because i want to be shure that is the right way.

How you think is the best way to create the "model" class for deserealize this Json?

---

Here is the Json downloaded from the HTTP API request, as you can see there is an array

```json
{
   "inputs":{
      "location":{
         "latitude":46.02,
         "longitude":22.999,
         "elevation":835.0
      },
      "meteo_data":{
         "radiation_db":"PVGIS-SARAH",
         "meteo_db":"ERA-Interim",
         "year_min":2010,
         "year_max":2011,
         "use_horizon":true,
         "horizon_db":null,
         "horizon_data":"DEM-calculated"
      },
      "mounting_system":{
         "fixed":{
            "slope":{
               "value":0,
               "optimal":false
            },
            "azimuth":{
               "value":0,
               "optimal":false
            },
            "type":"free-standing"
         }
      },
      "pv_module":{
         "technology":null,
         "peak_power":null,
         "system_loss":null
      }
   },
   "outputs":{
      "hourly":[
         {
            "time":"20100101:0010",
            "Gb(i)":0.0,
            "Gd(i)":0.0,
            "Gr(i)":0.0,
            "H_sun":0.0,
            "T2m":6.44,
            "WS10m":1.64,
            "Int":0.0
         },
         {
            "time":"20100101:0110",
            "Gb(i)":0.0,
            "Gd(i)":0.0,
            "Gr(i)":0.0,
            "H_sun":0.0,
            "T2m":6.55,
            "WS10m":1.52,
            "Int":0.0
         },
         {
            "time":"20100101:0210",
            "Gb(i)":0.0,
            "Gd(i)":0.0,
            "Gr(i)":0.0,
            "H_sun":0.0,
            "T2m":6.66,
            "WS10m":1.39,
            "Int":0.0
         }
      ]
   },
   "meta":{
      "inputs":{
         "location":{
            "description":"Selected location",
            "variables":{
               "latitude":{
                  "description":"Latitude",
                  "units":"decimal degree"
               },
               "longitude":{
                  "description":"Longitude",
                  "units":"decimal degree"
               },
               "elevation":{
                  "description":"Elevation",
                  "units":"m"
               }
            }
         },
         "meteo_data":{
            "description":"Sources of meteorological data",
            "variables":{
               "radiation_db":{
                  "description":"Solar radiation database"
               },
               "meteo_db":{
                  "description":"Database used for meteorological variables other than solar radiation"
               },
               "year_min":{
                  "description":"First year of the calculations"
               },
               "year_max":{
                  "description":"Last year of the calculations"
               },
               "use_horizon":{
                  "description":"Include horizon shadows"
               },
               "horizon_db":{
                  "description":"Source of horizon data"
               }
            }
         },
         "mounting_system":{
            "description":"Mounting system",
            "choices":"fixed, vertical_axis, inclined_axis, two_axis",
            "fields":{
               "slope":{
                  "description":"Inclination angle from the horizontal plane",
                  "units":"degree"
               },
               "azimuth":{
                  "description":"Orientation (azimuth) angle of the (fixed) PV system (0 = S, 90 = W, -90 = E)",
                  "units":"degree"
               }
            }
         },
         "pv_module":{
            "description":"PV module parameters",
            "variables":{
               "technology":{
                  "description":"PV technology"
               },
               "peak_power":{
                  "description":"Nominal (peak) power of the PV module",
                  "units":"kW"
               },
               "system_loss":{
                  "description":"Sum of system losses",
                  "units":"%"
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "outputs":{
         "hourly":{
            "type":"time series",
            "timestamp":"hourly averages",
            "variables":{
               "Gb(i)":{
                  "description":"Beam (direct) irradiance on the inclined plane (plane of the array)",
                  "units":"W/m2"
               },
               "Gd(i)":{
                  "description":"Diffuse irradiance on the inclined plane (plane of the array)",
                  "units":"W/m2"
               },
               "Gr(i)":{
                  "description":"Reflected irradiance on the inclined plane (plane of the array)",
                  "units":"W/m2"
               },
               "H_sun":{
                  "description":"Sun height",
                  "units":"degree"
               },
               "T2m":{
                  "description":"2-m air temperature",
                  "units":"degree Celsius"
               },
               "WS10m":{
                  "description":"10-m total wind speed",
                  "units":"m/s"
               },
               "Int":{
                  "description":"1 means solar radiation values are reconstructed"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the deserealized class create automatically from Json2csharp web site:

`// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);`

```
public class Location
{
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
    public double elevation { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Variables variables { get; set; }
}

public class MeteoData
{
    public string radiation_db { get; set; }
    public string meteo_db { get; set; }
    public int year_min { get; set; }
    public int year_max { get; set; }
    public bool use_horizon { get; set; }
    public object horizon_db { get; set; }
    public string horizon_data { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Variables variables { get; set; }
}

public class Slope
{
    public int value { get; set; }
    public bool optimal { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class Azimuth
{
    public int value { get; set; }
    public bool optimal { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class Fixed
{
    public Slope slope { get; set; }
    public Azimuth azimuth { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class MountingSystem
{
    public Fixed @fixed { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string choices { get; set; }
    public Fields fields { get; set; }
}

public class PvModule
{
    public object technology { get; set; }
    public object peak_power { get; set; }
    public object system_loss { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Variables variables { get; set; }
}

public class Inputs
{
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public MeteoData meteo_data { get; set; }
    public MountingSystem mounting_system { get; set; }
    public PvModule pv_module { get; set; }
}

public class Hourly
{
    public string time { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Gb(i)")]
    public double GbI { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Gd(i)")]
    public double GdI { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Gr(i)")]
    public double GrI { get; set; }
    public double H_sun { get; set; }
    public double T2m { get; set; }
    public double WS10m { get; set; }
    public double Int { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
    public Variables variables { get; set; }
}

public class Outputs
{
    public List<Hourly> hourly { get; set; }
}

public class Latitude
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class Longitude
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class Elevation
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class Variables
{
    public Latitude latitude { get; set; }
    public Longitude longitude { get; set; }
    public Elevation elevation { get; set; }
    public RadiationDb radiation_db { get; set; }
    public MeteoDb meteo_db { get; set; }
    public YearMin year_min { get; set; }
    public YearMax year_max { get; set; }
    public UseHorizon use_horizon { get; set; }
    public HorizonDb horizon_db { get; set; }
    public Technology technology { get; set; }
    public PeakPower peak_power { get; set; }
    public SystemLoss system_loss { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Gb(i)")]
    public GbI GbI { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Gd(i)")]
    public GdI GdI { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Gr(i)")]
    public GrI GrI { get; set; }
    public HSun H_sun { get; set; }
    public T2m T2m { get; set; }
    public WS10m WS10m { get; set; }
    public Int Int { get; set; }
}

public class RadiationDb
{
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class MeteoDb
{
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class YearMin
{
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class YearMax
{
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class UseHorizon
{
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class HorizonDb
{
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class Fields
{
    public Slope slope { get; set; }
    public Azimuth azimuth { get; set; }
}

public class Technology
{
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class PeakPower
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class SystemLoss
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class GbI
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class GdI
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class GrI
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class HSun
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class T2m
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class WS10m
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class Int
{
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public Inputs inputs { get; set; }
    public Outputs outputs { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Inputs inputs { get; set; }
    public Outputs outputs { get; set; }
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried this 2 ways to deserialize this single object

Attempt #1:

```
public Root DeserialiceJson(string jsonResponse)
{
    Root deserializedJsonClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(jsonResponse);

    return deserializedJsonClass;
}
```

And this one - attempt #2:

```
public List<Root> DeserialiceJsonArray(string jsonResponse)
{
    List<Root> deserializedJsonClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(jsonResponse);

    return deserializedJsonClass;
}
```

None of them works.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: What do you mean by `None works`? What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: IMHO use the output of this json tool as a guide, then edit the class definitions by hand to create the types you actually need.

Answer (score 1):

In your JSON object, your structure for  "output" in "meta" is different from the one in the other output in Root object.

you are getting a List at one place while a single object at the second place. you should define a proper format for receiving this JSON.

For now you can use these classes.

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
public class Location
{
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
    public double elevation { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Variables variables { get; set; }
}

public class MeteoData
{
    public string radiation_db { get; set; }
    public string meteo_db { get; set; }
    public int year_min { get; set; }
    public int year_max { get; set; }
    public bool use_horizon { get; set; }
    public object horizon_db { get; set; }
    public string horizon_data { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Variables variables { get; set; }
}

public class Slope
{
    public int value { get; set; }
    public bool optimal { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class Azimuth
{
    public int value { get; set; }
    public bool optimal { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class Fixed
{
    public Slope slope { get; set; }
    public Azimuth azimuth { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class MountingSystem
{
    public Fixed @fixed { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string choices { get; set; }
    public Fields fields { get; set; }
}

public class PvModule
{
    public object technology { get; set; }
    public object peak_power { get; set; }
    public object system_loss { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Variables variables { get; set; }
}

public class Inputs
{
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public MeteoData meteo_data { get; set; }
    public MountingSystem mounting_system { get; set; }
    public PvModule pv_module { get; set; }
}

public class Hourly
{
    public string time { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Gb(i)")]
    public string GbI { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Gd(i)")]
    public double GdI { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Gr(i)")]
    public string GrI { get; set; }
    public string H_sun { get; set; }
    public string T2m { get; set; }
    public string WS10m { get; set; }
    public string Int { get; set; }
}

public class Outputs
{
    public List<Hourly> hourly { get; set; }
}

public class Latitude
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class Longitude
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class Elevation
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class Variables
{
    public Latitude latitude { get; set; }
    public Longitude longitude { get; set; }
    public Elevation elevation { get; set; }
    public RadiationDb radiation_db { get; set; }
    public MeteoDb meteo_db { get; set; }
    public YearMin year_min { get; set; }
    public YearMax year_max { get; set; }
    public UseHorizon use_horizon { get; set; }
    public HorizonDb horizon_db { get; set; }
    public Technology technology { get; set; }
    public PeakPower peak_power { get; set; }
    public SystemLoss system_loss { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Gb(i)")]
    public GbI GbI { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Gd(i)")]
    public GdI GdI { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Gr(i)")]
    public GrI GrI { get; set; }
    public HSun H_sun { get; set; }
    public T2m T2m { get; set; }
    public WS10m WS10m { get; set; }
    public Int Int { get; set; }
}

public class RadiationDb
{
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class MeteoDb
{
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class YearMin
{
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class YearMax
{
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class UseHorizon
{
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class HorizonDb
{
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class Fields
{
    public Slope slope { get; set; }
    public Azimuth azimuth { get; set; }
}

public class Technology
{
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class PeakPower
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class SystemLoss
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class GbI
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class GdI
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class GrI
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class HSun
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class T2m
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class WS10m
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string units { get; set; }
}

public class Int
{
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class Meta
{
    public Inputs inputs { get; set; }
    public Outputs2 outputs { get; set; }
}

public class Hourly2
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
    public Variables variables { get; set; }
}
public class Outputs2
{
    public Hourly2 hourly { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public Inputs inputs { get; set; }
    public Outputs outputs { get; set; }
    public Meta meta { get; set; }
}
```

and Deserialize Like this

```
   var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
```